# Django ORM Queries differences

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

What is the difference between these queries? Output looks the same.

1)

```
>>> Movie.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Movie: Film 1>, <Movie: Film 2>, <Movie: Film 3>]>
```

2. 

```
>>> Movie.objects.prefetch_related('projection_set').all()
<QuerySet [<Movie: Film 1>, <Movie: Film 2>, <Movie: Film 3>]>
```

3. 

```
>>> Movie.objects.prefetch_related('projection_set')
<QuerySet [<Movie: Film 1>, <Movie: Film 2>, <Movie: Film 3>]>
```

```
>>> one = Movie.objects.all()
>>> two = Movie.objects.prefetch_related('projection_set').all()
>>> three = Movie.objects.prefetch_related('projection_set')

# How SQL looks like:
>>> print(one.query)
SELECT "cinemas_movie"."id", "cinemas_movie"."title", "cinemas_movie"."minimum_age" FROM "cinemas_movie"
>>> print(two.query)
SELECT "cinemas_movie"."id", "cinemas_movie"."title", "cinemas_movie"."minimum_age" FROM "cinemas_movie"
>>> print(three.query)
SELECT "cinemas_movie"."id", "cinemas_movie"."title", "cinemas_movie"."minimum_age" FROM "cinemas_movie"
```

Comment: There is no difference between these. Except that the `.prefetch_related(..)` will fetch also the related `Projection`s for all `Movie`s in one extra query.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem but SQL looks the same. Take a look. I updated my post.

Comment: that is because it is loaded in *one extra query*.